# How to set reactive value to default in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a problem with updating a reactive value in shiny.

So what my app basically does, is to save textInputs from the user.
When the user decides to upload all text inputs, I want to reset the textInputs.

Following example code:

**ui.R**

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("words", "Please enter a word"), 

    actionButton("submit_new_word", "Save"), # this submits each single word
    textOutput("submitted_new_words"), # this show all submitted words

    actionButton("submit_upload", "Upload my Results") # this uploads all submitted words
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  words_submitted <- paste("") # initial value 

  w_submitted <- eventReactive(input$submit_new_word, {
    words_submitted <- paste(words_submitted, " ", input$words)
    words_submitted <<- words_submitted

    updateTextInput(session, 
                    inputId = "words",
                    value = "") 

    return(words_submitted)
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)

  output$submitted_new_words <- renderText({
    w_submitted()
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit_upload, {
    # saveData(data_final) # upload, not needed for example here

    words_submitted <<- paste("")
  })
}
```

If you try this minimal example, you will see that the text inputs will be resetted,
but only *after* the "Save" button is clicked again.

I however would like to have the text inputs to be resetted when the "submit_upload" button is clicked.

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably best to do it with some sort of `reactive`. The way shiny works is that if there is no reactivity attached to it wont invalidate (refresh) anything on the client side such as `renderText`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarPanel(
                textInput("words", "Please enter a word"), 

                actionButton("submit_new_word", "Save"), # this submits each single word
                textOutput("submitted_new_words"), # this show all submitted words

                actionButton("submit_upload", "Upload my Results") # this uploads all submitted words
        )
)

v <- reactiveValues()

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        v$words_submitted <- paste("") # initial value 

        observeEvent(input$submit_new_word, {
                v$words_submitted <- paste(v$words_submitted, " ", input$words)
                updateTextInput(session, inputId = "words",value = "") 
        }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)

        output$submitted_new_words <- renderText({
                v$words_submitted
        })

        observeEvent(input$submit_upload, {
                # saveData(data_final) # upload, not needed for example here
                v$words_submitted <- paste("")
        })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```